# The compiler failed with error code -1073741502

Tags: iis-7

I have site that is hosted on the window server 2008 R2 with IIS7 since last 2 years now it suddenly  start giving error: The compiler failed with error code -1073741502 at clicking for any page on menu bar. However before this login page is running normally.

Event log error for this shows error code 3007 i.e. External Component has thrown exception in the eventlog viewer - but this site was working fine from last few months so how it can give exception for external component now.

There may be application pool issue - with this site

Currently I am using 'local system' as application pool as database is placed on the same the server.

Please suggest how to overcome this problem. May be some tips regarding setting of application pool can help me.

Thanks